# Invalid executable directory: ../emulator

Tags: android-studio, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to get the Android Emulator working with Ionic 2. Here is my setup...

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/anthonygordon/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In Android Studio I set up a AVD `Nexus_5_API_24`

And I get the following error when I run `ionic run android`

```
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_24


Waiting for emulator to start...


[140736250184640]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/opengl/EmuglBackendScanner.cpp:37:Invalid executable directory: ../emulator
[140736250184640]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/opengl/EmuglBackendScanner.cpp:37:Invalid executable directory: ../emulator

[140736250184640]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts ?? I'm stuck

Comment: you ever find a solution?

Comment: did you recently update your version of android studio?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, got a partial answer. I was having this problem when I was trying to launch an emulator with just the regular android sdk command

`emulator -avd <name of avd>`

When I ran `which emulator` it pointed to `/usr/local/bin/emulator` but not the emulator in the android sdk root at `/Users/<user name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator`

So I just ran that one with the following.

`/Users/<user name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd <emulator name>`

and it launched without a hitch.

I've never used ionic, but I would guess it's pointing to the wrong binary for emulator.  Maybe try and remove the emulator binary from the /usr/local/bin?

Comment: Thank you, had the same problem for months, this answer helped me realize I had the SDK installed in two different places. Also saved 48Gb when I cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that 'emulator' is trying to run from a relative path:

`Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386'`

I'm not 100% sure how to fix this at the core level. My solution was similar to MikeSchem by starting the emulator manually with the absolute path of the  emulator directory:

`/Users/<USER>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_24`

In my .profile:

```
function androidstart() {
    /Users/<USER>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_24;  
}
alias androidstart='androidstart'
```